# How to add a Group of data with only one unique group ID using C# in MSSQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to create a group of registered clients using different products, categories and sub categories.
I am using asp.net C# and updating database using entity model.

```
                int PID = Convert.ToInt32(ddProduct.SelectedValue);

                if (isValidName(txtGroupName.Text))
                {
                    if (ddBusinessCategory.SelectedValue == "0")
                    {
                        var clients = db.Client_Master.Where(c => c.InquiredFor == PID).ToList();

                        foreach (var clt in clients)
                        {
                            Group_Master gobj = new Group_Master();
                            gobj.GName = txtGroupName.Text;
                            gobj.ProductID = PID;
                            gobj.CatID = null;
                            gobj.SubCatID = null;
                            gobj.ClientID = clt.CID;
                            gobj.CreatedBy = Convert.ToInt32(((User_Master)Session["User"]).UID);
                            gobj.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                            db.Group_Master.AddObject(gobj);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (ddSubCategory.SelectedValue == "0")
                        {

                            int CID = Convert.ToInt32(ddBusinessCategory.SelectedValue);

                            var clients = db.Client_Master.Where(c => c.InquiredFor == PID && c.BusinessCategory == CID).ToList();

                            foreach (var clt in clients)
                            {
                                Group_Master gobj = new Group_Master();
                                gobj.GName = txtGroupName.Text;
                                gobj.ProductID = PID;
                                gobj.CatID = CID;
                                gobj.SubCatID = null;
                                gobj.ClientID = clt.CID;
                                gobj.CreatedBy = Convert.ToInt32(((User_Master)Session["User"]).UID);
                                gobj.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                                db.Group_Master.AddObject(gobj);
                                db.SaveChanges();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int CID = Convert.ToInt32(ddBusinessCategory.SelectedValue);
                            int SID = Convert.ToInt32(ddSubCategory.SelectedValue);

                            var clients = db.Client_Master.Where(c => c.InquiredFor == PID && c.BusinessCategory == CID && c.SubCategory == SID).ToList();

                            foreach (var clt in clients)
                            {
                                Group_Master gobj = new Group_Master();
                                gobj.GName = txtGroupName.Text;
                                gobj.ProductID = PID;
                                gobj.CatID = CID;
                                gobj.SubCatID = SID;
                                gobj.ClientID = clt.CID;
                                gobj.CreatedBy = Convert.ToInt32(((User_Master)Session["User"]).UID);
                                gobj.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                                db.Group_Master.AddObject(gobj);
                                db.SaveChanges();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Groups();
                }
```

I tried to add Group ID using many ways but didn't succeed.
Please suggest me how can I solve this.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this by taking the ID of last data of list and save as a group ID so, with the help of this we get unique group ID.

```
if (ddBusinessCategory.SelectedValue == "0")
                    {
                        var clients = db.Client_Master.Where(c => c.InquiredFor == PID).ToList();

                        int GrpID = 0;

                        if (clients.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var clt in clients)
                            {
                                if (ProductGrp(PID, clt.CID))
                                {
                                    Group_Master gobj = new Group_Master();
                                    gobj.GrpID = 0;
                                    gobj.GName = txtGroupName.Text;
                                    gobj.ProductID = PID;
                                    gobj.CatID = null;
                                    gobj.SubCatID = null;
                                    gobj.ClientID = clt.CID;
                                    gobj.CreatedBy = Convert.ToInt32(((User_Master)Session["User"]).UID);
                                    gobj.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                                    db.Group_Master.AddObject(gobj);
                                    db.SaveChanges();
                                    GrpID = gobj.GID;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "myscript()", "bootbox.alert({title: '<b>Error</b>',message: '<b>Group already exist.</b>',});", true);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            List<Group_Master> ggobj = db.Group_Master.Where(g => g.ProductID == PID && g.CatID == null && g.SubCatID == null).ToList();
                            foreach (var gid in ggobj)
                            {
                                if (gid.GrpID == 0)
                                {
                                    Group_Master gmobj = db.Group_Master.Single(s => s.GID == gid.GID);
                                    gmobj.GrpID = GrpID;
                                    db.SaveChanges();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "myscript()", "bootbox.alert({title: '<b>Error</b>',message: '<b>No Clients exist.</b>',});", true);
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create new table ClientsProducts, which will have reference to Client ID and Product ID. This is called One-to-Many Relationships.
You can read here about this [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561).

Comment: I am creating group on the basis of 1 Only Products, 2. Product with 1 main category and 3. Last Product with main categories as well as sub categories..